# what's best way for awk to check arbitrary integer precision

Tags: awk, precision, arbitrary-precision

from GNU gawk's page

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Checking-for-MPFR.html
```

they have a formula to check arbitrary precision

```
function adequate_math_precision(n) { return (1 != (1+(1/(2^(n-1))))) }
```

My question is : wouldn't it be more efficient by staying within integer math domain with a formula such as

```
( 2^abs(n) - 1 ) % 2   # note 2^(n-1) vs. 2^|n| - 1
```

Since any power of 2 must also be even, then subtracting 1 must always be odd, then its modulo (%) over 2 becomes indicator function for is_odd() for `n >= 0`, while the `abs(n)` handles the cases where it's negative.

Or does the modulo necessitate a casting to float point, thus nullifying any gains ?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. Let's tackle it.

The proposed snippet aims at checking wether gawk was invoked with the `-M` option.

I'll attach some digression on that option at the bottom.

The argument `n` of the function is the floating point precision needed for whatever operation you'll have to perform. So, say your script is in a library somewhere and will get called but you have no control over it. You'll run that function at the beginning of the script to promptly throw exception and bail out, suggesting that the end result will be wrong due to lack of bits to store numbers.

Your code stays in the integer realm: a power of two of an integer is an integer. There is no need to use `abs(n)` here, because there is no point in specifying how many bits you'll need as a negative number in the first place.

Then you subtract one from an even, integer number. Now, unless `n=0`, in which case `2^0=1` and then your code reads `(1 - 1) % 2 = 0`, your snippet shall always return `1`, because the quotient (`%`) of an odd number divided by two is 1.

Problem is: you are trying to calculate a potentially stupidly large number in a function that should check if you are able to do so in the first place.

> Since any power of 2 must also be even, then subtracting 1 must always
> be odd, then its modulo (%) over 2 becomes indicator function for
> is_odd() for n >= 0, while the abs(n) handles the cases where it's
> negative.

Except when `n=0` as we discussed above, you are right. The snippet will tell that any power of 2 is even, and any power of 2, minus 1, is odd. We were discussing another subject entirely thought.

Let's analyze the other function instead:

```
return (1 != (1+(1/(2^(n-1)))))
```

Remember that booleans in awk runs like this: `0=false` and non zero equal true. So, if `1+x` where `x` is a very small number, typically a large power of two (`2^122` in the example page) is mathematically guaranteed to be `!=1`, in the digital world that's not the case. At one point, floating computation will reach a precision rock bottom, will be rounded down, and `x=0` will be suddenly declared. At that point, the arbitrary precision function will return `0`: false: 1 is equal 1.

---

#### A larger discussion on types and data representation

The page you link explains precision for gawk invoked with the `-M` option. This sounds like technoblahblah, let's decipher it.

At one point, your OS architecture has to decide how to store data, how to represent it in memory so that it can be accessed again and displayed. Terms like Integer, Float, Double, Unsigned Integer are examples of data representation. We here are addressing Integer representation: how is an integer stored in memory?

A 32-bit system will use 4 bytes to represent and integer, which in turn determines how larger the integer will be. The 32 bits are read from most significative (MSB) to less significative (LSB) and if signed, one bit will represent the sign (the MSB typically, drastically reducing the max size of the integer).

If asked to compute a large number, a machine will try to fit in in the max number available. If the end result is larger than that, you have overflow and end up with a wrong result or an error. Many online challenges typically ask you to write code for arbitrary long loops or large sums, then test it with inputs that will break the 64bit barrier, to see if you master proper types for indexes.

AWK is not a strongly typed language. Meaning, any variable can store data, regardless of the type. The data type can change and it is determined at runtime by the interpreter, so that the developer doesn't need to care. For instance:

```
$awk '{a="this is text"; print a; a=2; print a; print a+3.0*2}'
-| this is text
-| 2
-| 8
```

In the example, `a` is text, then is an integer and can be summed to a floating point number and printed as integer without any special type handling.

The [Arbitrary Precision Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arbitrary-Precision-Integers.html) presents the following snippet:

```
$ gawk -M 'BEGIN {
>   s = 2.0
>   for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
>       s = s * (s - 1) + 1
>   print s
> }'
-| 113423713055421845118910464
```

There is some math voodoo behind, we will skip that. Since `s` is interpreted as a floating point number, the end result is computed as floating point.

Try to input that number on Windows calculator as decimal, and it will fail. Although you can compute it as a binary. You'll need the programmer setting and to add up to 53 bits to be able to fit it as unsigned integer.

53 is a magic number here: with the `-M` option, gawk uses arbitrary precision for numbers. In other words, it commandeers how many bits are necessary, track them and breaks free of the native OS architecture. The default option says that gawk will allocate 53 bits for any given arbitrary number. Fun fact, the actual result of that snippet is wrong, and it would take up to 100 bits to compute correctly.

To implement arbitrary large numbers handling, gawk relies on an external library called MPFR. Provided with an arbitrary large number, MPFR will handle the memory allocation and bit requisition to store it. However, the interface between gawk and MPFR is not perfect, and gawk can't always control the type that MPFR will use. In case of integers, that's not an issue. For floating point numbers, that will result in rounding errors.

This brings us back to the snippet at the beginning: if gawk was called with the `-M` option, numbers up to `2^53` can be stored as integers. Floating points will be smaller than that (you'll need to make the comma disappear somehow, or rather *represent* it spending some of the bits allocated for that number, just like the sign). Following the example of the page, and asking an arbitrary precision larger than 32, the snippet will return TRUE only if the `-M` option was passed, otherwise `1/2^(n-1)` will be rounded down to be `0`.

Comment: thanks for the very thorough response. These days, instead of calling a function each time to check it, i simply create a GMP-Indicator flag upfront by testing whether `2^-2^2^2^2` is non-zero (`gmp`) or not (`no bigint`). So instead of measuring the `ulp`, I'm testing with a value orders of magnitude smaller than even denormalized min, so any language without a `big-int/big-float` add-on definitely make it go to zero. This value is also rather near-future proof, since even 128-bit quadruple precision `FP`'s denormalized min is woefully short to represent `4.99119e-19729`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto this should be a response

Comment: you want me to post a response even though I'm the OP ?